# Ignore hidden files and directories with obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, directory, hidden

How can I execute hidden directory and files programmatically?

> i.e: .DS_Store

I want to execute all the hidden files and directories which start with the "."

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: execute, I'm sorry for any ambiguity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `NSFileManager` with `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles`.

For example:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *theFiles =  [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Anne/Desktop/"]
                                includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey]
                                                   options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                     error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",theFiles);
```

Comment: This. It has the benefit of also skipping files that are hidden because they have their invisible attribute set.

Comment: I checked the NSLog-print of "theFiles" and it works. The hidden file is executed. Many thanks