# Searching for visible files using contentsOfDirectoryAtPath and storing them in Objective-C NSArray

Tags: objective-c, file, nsarray, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignore hidden files and directories with obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053820/ignore-hidden-files-and-directories-with-obj-c)

I'm loading the contents of a folder into an array:

```
    NSString *asWindowName = [_errMessage stringValue] ; 
    //which returns the correct folder path '/Users/ronny/Desktop/FLVs'

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *atFilesOriginal   = [fileManager
                           contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:asWindowName
                           error:&error];
```

This is what I get:

```
".DS_Store",
".flv",
"File-170184.mp4",
"File-758f10cee9011a66f91dd8e01c6b5427.mp4",
"File2.webloc",
"File-c71e8.mp4",
"File-.webloc"
```

I wonder if it is possible to get only visible files.

Any clues? Tia, Ronald

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053820/ignore-hidden-files-and-directories-with-obj-c

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, I just found it , thanks.